# Foxit PDF SDK - How to efficiently Update UI Extension methods

Tags: android, pdf, sdk, foxit, foxit-reader

I am working on Foxit PDF SDK implemented in our app. Anyone who have used it knows that they have UiExtension library which provides us the functionality of the pdf from its core libraries. Now if we have to change something in any tool provided by Foxit, we have to make changes in UiExtension. Every things works great but the problem is now we have to update the SDK and UiExtension code will be updated and everything will be replaced i.e we have to compare every file and get the changes we made. I couldn't figure out the efficient way to make changes in UiExtension so that we wont have to go through the same trauma again and update every file. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually only major version, like version 5.x to 6.x, changes will result in the API from the Foxit PDF SDK for iOS/Android to change.  Since, the UIExtension is uses the Foxit PDF SDK for iOS/Android to provide you the UI from either iOS or Android.  If you are just doing a minor change, like version 6.3 to 6.4, the changes in the API are less likely.  In cases of minor changes, you can just keep your old UIExtension.

The best way to trouble shoot this is to integrate the the UIExtension project into your iOS or android project.  This way you can switch out the Foxit PDF SDK library and see what errors it may cause with your project.  For details on this, please see "Customize UI implementation through the source code" in [FoxitDeveloperGuideForiOS](https://developers.foxitsoftware.com/kb/article/developer-guide-foxit-pdf-sdk-for-mobile-ios/) or [FoxitDeveloperGuideForAndroid](https://developers.foxitsoftware.com/kb/article/developer-guide-foxit-pdf-sdk-for-mobile-android/).